# Does using SSL really prevent hackers from hacking my Sessions variables?

Tags: php, security, ssl

My website is 100% dependant on Sessions variables.

When you login on the server, it sets the Session to the client username and each page checks if the username is set and use that variable for posting ads and more... but if someone hacks that variable and change it to any other username he can then login and delete all stuff, see personal informations etc

So a friend of mine told me that using SSL would prevent all hackers from sniffing and from hijacking my website, is that right? 'Cause I might change my server and it doesn't have SSL on it, so I was wondering if it's worth to pay for it? or if there was another solution

Thanks alot
Kevin

Comment: You don't understand how sessions work. Even without ssl it is impossible (by definition) to *steal session data* with sniffing.

Comment: alright so it is useless in my case?

Comment: Perhaps your biggest threat in this case is from [cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) -- where someone creates links into your website, linked via `<img>` tags or something similar on another website (facebook, webforums, HTML-based emails, etc.), that causes your server to perform actions on behalf of the logged-in user. If you use `GET` requests for only "safe" actions, it'll help immensely. Expiring using sessions after a certain amount of inactivity can reduce the window of exposure.

Comment: I only use $_SESSION  for important stuff, basic one use GET like page language etc... is that ok?

Comment: @KevAlmighty: When I drive I use steering wheel to turn and pedal to accelerate. Is that ok? Could you say am I good driver or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using https encrypts the cookies sent, including your session cookie. This is very secure. Hackers can still take jabs at your network security by sending false session cookies, but you're pretty safe because hackers wouldn't be able to easily get ahold of a session id while using https.

Comment: I'd like to add that SSL is not really secure at all anymore - you should really switch to [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)! Apart from that this is a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are really asking two questions, one about SSL and one about sessions - so, here's two answers:

Sessions work by giving the user a cookie and storing a list of the session variables on the server.  In PHP, that cookie is named PHPSESSID by default.  You can probably see a lot of them if you look at the cookies in your browser right now.  The value of that cookie will be a bunch of hard-to-guess gibberish characters.  When you set a session variable, say $_SESSION['username']='kevin', the "username=kevin" part is stored on the server.

If the attacker can guess or obtain that cookie, they can install it on their browser and become "kevin," unless you have other countermeasures.  But, for the user to change their session to someone else, they would have to hack your server to change the session files there.  The name "kevin" is never sent to the user.

SSL is not a magic security solution, but if you are concerned about a malicious user viewing or taking over another user's session, it's probably worth the investment.

An Internet cafe is a simple example.  Lots of people gather and use the WiFi.  Web pages are going through the air everywhere - even though your own body.  It's trivial for an attacker to also capture the web pages of other users - this includes their session token.  It's so easy, that there's a program called FireSheep that made becoming another user point-and-click simple for many web sites.

SSL protects those web pages, and the session cookie, so that only the server and the authorized user can read them.  An attacker can still capture the data going through the air, but it is just gibberish to them.